# Why Temporary Table is not Table Expression?

Tags: sql-server

I understand there are 4 types of table expression such as CTE, Derived table, View, and Inline table-valued functions.

My question is that Temporary Tables seem exactly the same but stored in TempDB. Why are Temporary Tables not included in Table expression?

I am using SQL Server.

Comment: A `VIEW` isn't an expression, it's an object. An Inline Table Value Function is also a type of object (a `FUNCTION`) not an expression. I'm not sure what you mean by "dervived" table. A CTE, however, is an expression. Like the others, a Temporary table is also an object, not an expression. You can find temporary tables, Views and iTVFs in `sys.objects` for the relevant database they are created in.

Comment: @Larnu nested `SELECT` statements -- both correlated and uncorrelated -- are formally called derived tables.

Comment: You're right, @JoelCoehoorn . Think not getting to physically speak or see a human being for so long is starting to get to me, I'm forgetting basics. :(

Comment: In SQL, theoretical concepts are muddied as most "objects" can change their "nature" e.g. a view can be considered an expression as it is just a named SQL query but if you add an index to it, it works more like a table. Then you have portioned views as well, which introduce various restrictions. # and @ Tables physically store data (on HDD) that can be modified by other queries, making them a variable. Select statement is heavily overloaded in sql and its underlying "nature" changes depending on surrounding statements e.g. `SELECT 1 / 0 FROM t` vs `IF EXISTS( SELECT 1 / 0 FROM t )`